# How to add a "Loading . . ."  dialog to an android app

Tags: android, dialog, loading

I have a simple android application to access a web service. I want to show a dialog `"Loading . . ."` until results are loaded and dismissed after loading the results. I have used this code but this doesn't show the loading message:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends Activity {
   private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.eretailer.com/";
   private static final String METHOD_NAME = "dataSender";
   private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.eretailer.com/dataSender/";
   private static final String URL = "http://175.157.128.207:8085/Eretailer/services/EretailerService?wsdl";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pd.setMessage("Loading. . .");
    pd.show();
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    pd.show();
    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {

        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;

        pd.dismiss();
           String str = s.toString();
           String arr1[] = str.split(" ");

           TextView tv = new TextView(this);

           for(int i = 0; i<arr1.length;i++){
           tv.append("order ID :"+arr1[i]+"\n");
          }
           setContentView(tv);

       } catch (Exception e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
}
```

How can I correct this problem ?

Comment: If `ht.call(` is blocking, you should run this on a different thread. Blocking `onCreate` will affect responsiveness and it seems likely that it would prevent the dialog from appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try as following code

```
 private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
         HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {

                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive s = response;

                pd.dismiss();
                   String str = s.toString();
                   String arr1[] = str.split(" ");

                   TextView tv = new TextView(this);

                   for(int i = 0; i<arr1.length;i++){
                   tv.append("order ID :"+arr1[i]+"\n");
                  }
                   setContentView(tv);

               } catch (Exception e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Resource : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: This code is just to give an idea how do it with AsyncTask and its possible that this code may not be exact that you want you have to alter some portion

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [Android-AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your Web Request. And start `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute()` of AsyncTask and close it in `onPostExecute()`(Update your UI here for result from Web response). Also put Web-Request code in `doInBackGround()` of AsyncTask..

For Example look at [Android AsyncTask Example](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/).

This will never block your **Main-UI Thread**. And better performance for User Experience.

Answer (score 0):

first comment pd.dismiss() first and check if its loading is coming then use pd.dismiss() after downloading complete.